# git http-backend show info when accessing per browser

Tags: apache-2.2, git, arch-linux

I'm currently hosting my own git-repos for my private projects. For this, I use Apache and the standard git *http-backend*.

Now, a repo can be accessed under an URL like this:

```
http://vcs.myserver.lc/git/Repo.git
```

With this URL, I can push, fetch and clone to/from this repo using [git](/questions/tagged/git). However, opening this URL in a Browser simply gives me a blank page and now I'm looking for a way to avoid this.

Instead, I'd like Apache to present a page with some infos like:

> This is not a web-page, this is a git-repo. You can clone this repo
>   using `git clone [URL]` ...

It would be nice if `[URL]` would be replaced with the current URL (using PHP for example), but plain HTML would be fine, too.

I know this should be possible since [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github) does the same with their repos.

I managed to do something similar for the `vcs.myserver.lc`-domain by specifying a `DocumentRoot` in the VHost-config file:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/http/vcs/
```

In this path, i put a simple `index.html`-file with basic instructions.

So, is their any simple way of showing an info side for browsers while the git-client can still work with the repo? Can I redirect browsers to a specific info-site?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's actually relatively simple. You need to tell apache to only use the git-http-backend for things git is interested in, which is anything that matches `^.*/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive)-pack)$`

Comment: Would you elaborate? Using `AliasMatch` with that expression doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out and your answer was the pointer I needed. I created an `AliasMatch ^/git/.*.git/$ <some_txt_file_with_basic_instructions>` to handle browsers and a `ScriptAliasMatch ^/git/(.*\.git/.*) /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/$1` where I previously had the textbook `ScriptAlias`.